# Powershell How to Handle Az Cli in a Try Catch Block

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I have the following code...

When the resource is not found an error is raised but the code continues to run...not sure why?

```
 try{
              
              $state=$(az synapse sql pool show --name $DB_NAME --resource-group $RG_NAME --workspace-name $WKSPC_NAME --query "status")

              Write-Host("State = $state")

              if($state -match "Paused")
              {
                Write-Host("Resume Pool xxx")
                
                az synapse sql pool resume --name $DB_NAME --resource-group $RG_NAME --workspace-name $WKSPC_NAME

                az synapse sql pool wait --sql-pool-name $DB_NAME --resource-group $RG_NAME --workspace-name $WKSPC_NAME --custom "state==Online"
              };
          
            
            }
            catch
            {
              Write-Host("Handle error - no need to do anything....")
            }
```

Comment: Found a useful article that may provide an answer....

https://matthorgan.xyz/blog/azcli-error-handling-in-powershell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `try-catch` block only catches terminating errors. Non-terminating errors, like the one thrown by the `az` command in this case, are not caught and do not stop the execution of the script. Use the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable and set to `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` at the beginning of your script.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

try {
    $state=$(az synapse sql pool show --name $DB_NAME --resource-group $RG_NAME --workspace-name $WKSPC_NAME --query "status")

    Write-Host("State = $state")

    if($state -match "Paused") {
        Write-Host("Resume Pool xxx")
        az synapse sql pool resume --name $DB_NAME --resource-group $RG_NAME --workspace-name $WKSPC_NAME
        az synapse sql pool wait --sql-pool-name $DB_NAME --resource-group $RG_NAME --workspace-name $WKSPC_NAME --custom "state==Online"
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Host("Handle error - no need to do anything....")
}
```